# How to join two lines in one

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cat

I have a problem with select of specify lines and join every second lines in one line.

i.e. I have two file:

```
cat lol1.txt
2015-11-15 12:44:34
Name    Value1  Value2
lol1    3   2
lol2    2   5
2015-11-15 12:44:44
Name    Value   Value2
lol1    7   1
lol2    5   1
2015-11-15 12:44:54
Name    Value   Value2
lol1    3   9
lol2    9   2
```

and

```
cat lol2.txt
2015-11-16 10:23:31
Name    Value   Value2
lol1    3   4   
lol2    4   7
2015-11-16 10:23:41
Name    Value   Value2
lol1    7   5
lol2    9   2
2015-11-16 10:23:51
Name    Value   Value2
lol1    2   4   
lol2    2   5
```

And command:

```
cat lol.txt lol2.txt | grep 'lol1\|2015'
```

returns:

```
2015-11-15 12:44:34
lol1    3   2
2015-11-15 12:44:44
lol1    7   1
2015-11-15 12:44:54
lol1    3   9
2015-11-16 10:23:31
lol1    3   4   
2015-11-16 10:23:41
lol1    7   5
2015-11-16 10:23:51
lol1    2   4
```

Now I have to join every second lines in one. I mean:

```
2015-11-15 12:44:34 lol1    3   2
2015-11-15 12:44:44 lol1    7   1
2015-11-15 12:44:54 lol1    3   9
2015-11-16 10:23:31 lol1    3   4
2015-11-16 10:23:41 lol1    7   5
2015-11-16 10:23:51 lol1    2   4
```

And another question. How to choose line with date and time with use something else than grep 2015, because in next year date will start from 2016 and i will have to change script.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do `... | grep ... | xargs -L 2` to join pairs of lines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell While being a good idea, that doesn't work for me. I doesn't respect the end of file.

Comment: @hek2mgl Ok, thanks for the input - I'll check tomorrow when my machine is booted up.. `seq 1 10 | xargs -L 2`

Comment: You don't need to use `cat`; you can simply specify the two files to `grep`.  But `awk` looks like the tool for the whole job.

Comment: Yes I know ude `cat`, `grep` and `awk` in one command is a really bad practice. I'll take it into consideration next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you planned to use `awk`, the `grep` can be saved, the `cat` is anyway useless.

This awk one-liner does your job.

```
awk '/^2015/{printf "%s%s",(NR>1?"\n":""),$0}/lol1/{printf " %s",$0}' f1 f2
```

#### Note

1. `f1, f2` are your two files. It gives expected output.
2. The line above doesn't follow the `every second line` rule, instead, it groups the `lol1` data by timestamp, which could be your real requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your method is the best and like you said my real requirement is different than `every second line`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe that to the following `awk` command:

```
... | awk 'NR%2{last=$0;next}{print last, $0}'
```

It stores the whole line into the variable `last` on odd lines and prints `last` plus the current line on even lines.

Or shorter:

```
... | awk '!(NR%2){print l, $0}{l=$0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue! You don't need cat/grep.

```
 $ awk '/^[0-9-]{10}/{printf $0 FS} /lol1/' lol1.txt
2015-11-15 12:44:34 lol1    3   2
2015-11-15 12:44:44 lol1    7   1
2015-11-15 12:44:54 lol1    3   9
```

you can extend the file list.  The first pattern is a simplistic date content pattern; based on your data should be enough, if not easy to convert to a better one.

Comment: Using `printf $0` is a very bad habit to get into, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead. Imagine the difference when `$0` contains a printf formatting string like `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '/-/{t=$0} /lol1/{print t, $0}' lol1.txt lol2.txt
2015-11-15 12:44:34 lol1    3   2
2015-11-15 12:44:44 lol1    7   1
2015-11-15 12:44:54 lol1    3   9
2015-11-16 10:23:31 lol1    3   4
2015-11-16 10:23:41 lol1    7   5
2015-11-16 10:23:51 lol1    2   4
```